# Show progressIndicator in a Flutter app while scanning barcode

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Here is my dart code:

```
class BarCodeScanner extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarCodeScannerState createState() => _BarCodeScannerState();
}

class _BarCodeScannerState extends State<BarCodeScanner> {
  var barcodeScanner;

  getBarcodeData() async {
    try {
      // final qrcoder = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
      //     '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      // if (!mounted) return;
      FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
              "#ff6666", "Cancel", false, ScanMode.DEFAULT)
          .listen((barcode) {
        /// barcode to be used
        this.barcodeScanner = barcode;
      }).onData((data) {
        // getGoodsData(data);
        print(data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      barcodeScanner = 'Falied to get Platform Version';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          getBarcodeData(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In Flutter I want to show progressIndicator while scanning barcode. Once scanning finished I want to disable the progressIndicator. I want to show progressIndicator while scanning. After scanning I want to show a dialog like which is available in the image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if your data coming from `getBarcodeStreamReceiver()` is a `Stream` then you need `StreamBuilder`

Comment: I am not understanding.My issue is progressindicator is not visible while scanning

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y&t=23s - the method `getBarcodeStreamReceiver()` returns a `Stream` so use that `Stream` inside `StreamBuilder` widget

Comment: btw why dont you use [scanBarcode](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_barcode_scanner/latest/flutter_barcode_scanner/FlutterBarcodeScanner/scanBarcode.html) which is easier in use?

Comment: i am new to flutter don't know which is best. i have googled barcode scanning and picked this scanning method

Comment: Please look at the above edited question

Comment: i Want to show progressIndicator like that

Comment: as i said use `StreamBuilder` (or `FutureBuilder` if you use `scanBarcode` method which returns a `Future`) - what is unclear in those two builder widgets?

Comment: Please provide some lines of code

Comment: you have some lines of code in the official documentation for those two widgets: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html